# Why are infinitesimal rotations commutative, whereas finite rotations are not?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Infinitesimal rotations commute and every finite rotation is the composition of infinitesimal rotations which should logically mean they also commute; but they don't. Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Infinitesimal rotations don't commute exactly if you're accurate enough. An infinitesimal rotation may be written as 
$$ \exp( i a A ) $$
where $a$ is an infinitesimal "angle" and $A$ is a combination of generators. Such an object doesn't commute with the analogous object $\exp(ibB)$ in general. Instead,
$$ \exp(iaA) \exp(ibB) = \exp(ibB) \exp(iaA) \exp(-ab [A,B] + O(a_i^3)) $$
where $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is the ordinary "commutator" of operators i.e. the generators (of the bases "vectors" $A,B$ of the Lie algebra associated with the Lie group). The equation above may be verified by carefully expanding the exponentials on both sides to the second order in $a$ or $b$, ignoring cubic and higher-order terms, but being careful about the ordering of $A$ and $B$ etc.

The failure of the infinitesimal rotations to commute is only expressed by a smaller angle $ab$ which is second order but the accumulation of these $O(a_i^2)$ terms is what makes finite rotations "obviously noncommuting". Why? Because if you want to interchange $N$ copies of $\exp(iaA)$ in $\exp(iNaA)$ with $M$ copies of $\exp(ibB)$ in $\exp(iNbB)$, you need to make $MN$ similar permutations, so assuming that $Ma$ and $Nb$ are finite, the factors of $MN$ (large) and $ab$ (small) cancel and you get a finite difference between the products written in the opposite orders.

Comment: If you want to play around with this numerically, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2Ca%5D%2C%5B0%2C-a%2C1%5D%5D.%5B%5B1%2Ca%2C0%5D%2C%5B-a%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D+-+%5B%5B1%2Ca%2C0%5D%2C%5B-a%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D.%5B%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2Ca%5D%2C%5B0%2C-a%2C1%5D%5D); here, you see that two rotations of an angle $a$ around the X and Z axis don't commute, but leave a remainder of order $a^2.$